# C++ Struct Value Initialization

Tags: c++

I was messing around with structs and noticed that of the following two examples, only one worked. Here they are:

```
struct Test
{ 
    char *name; 
    int age; 
}; 

Test p1 = { "hi", 5 };
//works


struct Test
{ 
    char *name; 
    int age; 
}p1; 

p1 = { "hi", 5 };
//error
```

How come the first one compiles and the second one doesn't? Isn't `p1` an object of `Test` either way? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first example you are *initializing* a struct with two values in a "brace initialization."  There is no support in C++ (or C) for *assigning* to a struct using a brace-enclosed list.

You could, however, create a new struct using brace initialization, then assign it to the old struct (`p`).  C++ (and C) does support assignment of one struct to another of the same type.

For example, in C++11:

```
p1 = Test{ "hi", 5 };
```

Comment: Okay, makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: The syntax for C is slightly different. I believe you need something like `p1 = (struct Test){"hi", 5"}`.

Comment: And C (actually C99) also supports even nicer syntax: `p = (struct XXX){.a=2, .b="def"};`

Comment: @nimrodm: As a C++ user, don't remind me how nice C99 struct init is.  :)

Answer (score 2):

The following does work with C++11:
(Compile with `g++ -std=c++11 init.cpp`)

```
#include <iostream>

struct XXX {
    int a;
    const char *b;
};

int main() {
    XXX x;
    x = XXX{1, "abc"};
    // or later...
    x = XXX{2, "def"};

    std::cout << x.b << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```